# How to generate Jacoco integration test report using offline instrumentation?

Tags: maven, unit-testing, integration-testing, code-coverage, jacoco

**Build tool**: Maven

**Reason to use offline instrumentation**: Removing Powermock is not an option

**Problem**: 
Both failsafe and surefire are run and reports are generated. However, jacoco.exec is generate but jacoco-it.exec is not. Apart from IT , offline instrumentation, coverage and reporting works fine.

This is the maven plugin configuration I use:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-instrument</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>instrument</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-report</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-report-integration</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>report-integration</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.15</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

To run the test i use maven clean install.

At the end of the test execution I get the following output:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.15:integration-test (integration-tests) @ elune ---
[INFO] Skipping execution of surefire because it has already been run for this configuration
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.8:report (default-report) @ elune ---
[INFO] Loading execution data file C:\Projects\elune\target\jacoco.exec
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'elune' with 4 classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.8:report-integration (default-report-integration) @ elune ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.
```

Another possible pointer might be that the de-instrumentation of the classes happens after the unit tests are run but before the integration tests. But I don't know if this is right or wrong:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.8:restore-instrumented-classes (default-restore-instrumented-classes) @ elune ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ elune ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Projects\elune\target\elune-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ elune ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.15:integration-test (default) @ elune ---
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: C:\Projects\elune\target\failsafe-reports
```

Any idea why the jacoco-it.exec is not showing up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the instrumentation of Integration Tests with the failsafe plugin are just not baked in. The restore-instrumented-classes goal defaults to the prepare-package phase which runs before the integration test phase: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/lifecycles.html - so it may be enough to move that goal into the post-integration-test phase:

```
<execution>
  <id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
  <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
  <goals>
    <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
  </goals>
</execution>
```

that may be enough. Otherwise you may be able to change the includes pattern of the surefire plugin to also include the integration tests (if that seems suitable in your case).

Answer (score 0):

The jacoco-it.exec is not showing up after I set the phrase.
command line is:
     mvn clean install -Djacoco.version=0.7.8  -DfailOnError=false -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true

**I finally found the problem was that I didn't add configuration jacoco-agent.destfile in maven-failsafe-plugin.**

```
<plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.15</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco-it.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-instrument</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>instrument</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

@rhinoceros.xn this is the plugin configuration that did the trick for me. But I use `mvn clean install` to run this

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-instrument</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>instrument</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report-integration</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report-integration</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: you're very kind. thanks for help.          I finally found the problem was that I didn't add configuration jacoco-agent.destfile in  maven-failsafe-plugin.